# How to split icons in two actionbars - top and bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have total 7 icons for my android app.
Can i split them for mobile in two actionbars top and bottom? I mean 2 icons in top actionbar and remaining icons should be in bottom actionbar.

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

And this: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html - Action Overflow section.

If you set this option then you will not have overflow menu, instead you will get split actionbar. But it won't work on android 2.x and lower. And also you don't have control how many items are in top actionbar.

Comment: @Pavan Kumar I have tested by making 2 action bar having 7 tabs but codes seems to be long.there should be some better method.

Comment: You can also put two icons in top ActionBar and create something that looks like actionbar at the bottom and put remaining icons there.

Answer (score 1):

The action bar can be automatically splitted if there is no place using the property splitActionBarWhenNarrow, example:

```
<application
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" > ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will have to do this in code, eg. instantiate the icons and add them to the correct actionbar view. There is no implementation logic for this available in the xml format as far as I know.